# why node version from JS and bash/shell does not match?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, powershell, electron

**The question is why the node versions do not match between JS and shell within each OS?**

here is the node version in **ubuntu** bash using `node -v`

[image]

here is the node version from JS in **ubuntu** using `console.log("NodeJS version = " + process.version);`

[image]

here is the node version in **windows** PowerShell using `node -v`

[image]

here is the node version from JS in **windows** using `console.log("NodeJS version = " + process.version);`

[image]

Comment: How are you getting a node js version in the *browser console*?

Comment: using process.version from an electron app

Comment: Then obviously the version of node bundled in your electron app is different than the version you are running on the OS. I added the electron tag to your question.

Comment: thanks, I tried installing the specific node version that I see from the electron in ubuntu, for example, `n 12.14.1` but I still see v13.1.0 in the bash

Comment: 1. This is too broad for stackoverflow. There are already questions with answers here about how to downgrade your nodejs version, and how to install multiple versions of nodejs, etc. Please pick *a single, **specific*** question to ask, and before posting it make sure that it's not a duplicate. 2. Why does it matter? Why do you have to have the same version installed on your host OS that you have in your electron app? Is there some specific problem you are experiencing? Because this seems to be an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The Node version that is bundled with Electron is *independent* of the one that might be installed on the system. Changing one doesn't change the other. Each Electron version bundles a certain Node version (see [this table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-releases)).

Comment: thanks to all, my apologies if its a xy type of question. However, I am curious because  I installed a specific node js using `n 12.14.1` then how `node -v` could still show me v13.1.0? this is not related to electron and shouldn't it show me the exact version which I just installed,?

Comment: @WasimAftab no, not necessarily. You almost certainly did not follow the correct procedure to downgrade an existing nodejs install (you can google that to get a feel for what you need to do), so it kept the "old" one and you're still seeing it. *Again*, why does it matter? What is the point of all of this? What's you *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks, I've got ideas from your valuable comments. I will work on that.